# CkEditor5 Custom Build creates empty editor

Tags: angular, ckeditor5

I'm trying to use my custom build in my Angular app. The standard classic build works fine but when I'm Import the custom build it gives me no error and the editor renders blank. I'm scratching my head here, been looking around and can't seem to find a solution.

Importing the CkEditor module and my custom build:

```
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';
// import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'; // The Classic build works fine.
import * as Editor from '../../../../../../../ckeditor5-custom/' // I'll create a npm-package for this when I get it working so I can keep it bundled in my node_modules.
```

constructing the editor as following:

```
 public Editor: any = Editor;
```

And my Html looks like this:

```
 <ckeditor formControlName="body" [editor]="Editor"></ckeditor>
```

I ran npm install in the custom build folder to get all the dependencies as well. I've tried to import from /ckeditor5-custom/build/ckeditor as well, same result.

I have also set the allowJs: true in my tsconfig. I must be missing something obvious here..

Angular CLI: v17.2.4
CkEditor-Angular: 7.0.1